# Renew Google OAuth Authorization Code

Tags: angularjs, cordova, typescript, oauth

I'm trying to set up a OAuth 2 system between my app and Google, in the process I received the authorization code, and I successfully exchanged it for access and id tokens. The problem is that every time after that I've tried running my code it's given me this error :

{error: "invalid_grant", error_description: "Code was already redeemed."}

Im using angular 2 on ionic 2, with cordova.

[Code used to exchange code for tokens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBeig.png)

[Code used to get authorization code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9SrY.png)

Comment: Glad you provided some code but doing so as images vs. code snippets in your question makes it hard for anyone to easily review and troubleshoot your code. I'd suggest updating your question to provide the code in a more accessible format. May also want to take a look at the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for some more information.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your response and advice, greatly appreciate it. I ended up figuring the issue out. There was a bug in my code where I wasn't correctly retrieving the authorization code from the URL. This question can be closed :)

Comment: Great, please checkout this help page on answering your own question. Or you could delete it if you would rather that option.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer